# convert the DataFrame from website into a list

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#scrape html from website and store 3rd DataFrame as our stock tickers - this is dictated to us by the structure of the html
stock_list = pd.read_html("https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/industry/stocklist.asp?bcind_ind=9535&bcind_period=3mo")
print(stock_list)
```

I wanted to convert it into a list:

```
#convert the DataFrame of stocks into a list so we can easily iterate over it
stocks = stock_list[1].dropna()[1:].tolist()
#set empty list o hold the stock price DataFrames that we can later concatenate into a master frame
df_list = []
#not all stocks will return data so set up an empty list to store the stock tickers that actually successfully returns data
used_stocks = []
#iterate over stock tickers in list and download relevant data, storing said data and successfully downloaded tickers along the way
for stock in stocks:
    try:
        data = pd.DataFrame(web.DataReader(stock,data_source='iex',start='01/01/2013')['close'])
        data.columns = [stock]
        df_list.append(data)
        used_stocks.append(stock)
    except:
        pass
#concatenate list of individual tciker price DataFrames into one master DataFrame
df = pd.concat(df_list,axis=1)
```

but it returns the error below:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'

How am i supposed to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, you want to debug and go to the line where the error occurs. For the part where your error is, the hint is provided by `tolist`. It is caused by this line

```
stocks = stock_list[1].dropna()[1:].tolist()
```

You can try this

```
stocks = stock_list[1].dropna()[1:].values.tolist()
print(stocks)
```

Getting you 10 rows by 2 columns. And then, you want to see if this is what you are expecting, and fix the next error.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_html` return list of dataframes.

Instead of converting it into the list, if your final goal is to iterate through that list you can use following code.

```
df_list = []
used_stocks = []

for index, row in stock_list[1].dropna()[1:].iterrows():
    #Get stock from row and process ahead.
```